# Adding OR condition to an array in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I want to add an OR condition to an array.

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($E$4:E="Foo") OR $E$4:E="Bar"
```

Update I think I found the answer in an example...use the + sign

```
=ArrayFormula(if((AG2:AG="Yes")+(AI2:AI<>""),"Ok","Blank"))
```

So

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($E$4:E="Foo") + $E$4:E="Bar"
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/if(($E$4:E="Foo") + $E$4:E="Bar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/(E4:E="Foo")+(E4:E="Bar")))
```

You can also use [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) with the pipe `|`

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/REGEXMATCH(E4:E,"^(Foo|Bar)$")))
```